# Нужна ли прописная буква в кавычках после слова "идея"?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Идея "Обучай, развлекая" не нова.

Идея "обучай, развлекая" не нова.

Как верно?

Comment: Идея «развлекая, обучай»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Идея "обучай, развлекая" не нова.**

Нет смысла использовать прописную букву, так как эта фраза в данном случае не является самостоятельным предложением. Это несогласованное определение: идея (какая?).

Comment: А правомерна ли тут запятая?

Comment: Оба варианта возможны и оба применяются в этой фразе. Оттенки смысла немного разные: обучай и попутно развлекай (добавочное действие деепричастия)  или обучай методом развлечения. Мне первый вариант больше нравится, а во втором нужен будет учитель-клоун. Например,  чтобы  запомнить правило, он сочинит детишкам сказку, споёт песенку.